# jQuery/Javascript sticky sidebar jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress plugin called Standard Widget Extentions which essentially uses jQuery to create a sticky floating sidebar. You can see this in action on a page on my site, its the sidebar with the social sharing buttons on the left http://turnnatural.com/2-seemingly-healthy-kitchen-items-you-need-to-toss-right-away-and-what-to-replace-them-with/

The issue I have is when you scroll it seems to "jitter" about and doesn't have a fluid movement. Is there some javascript/jquery/css changes to fix this?

I have asked in the forum of the creator but I get no response and I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any stickiness in the sidebar...

Comment: Its the social icons on the left had side

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I want the movement to be smooth